# how do i reduce the size of the Cluster Icon in google maps ?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
var clusterStyles = [
        {
            textColor: 'white',
            url: 'http://example.com/image.png',
            height: 40,
            width: 40,
            textSize: 14
        },
```

I'm fetching the icon image from a url and tried to adjust the size by adjusting the height and the width, now the image icon just cuts into half with the other half gone. how do i reduce the size without cutting off part of the image?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle example

Answer (score 1):

Try the styles parameter
set style options for marker clusters (these are the default styles)

```
 mOptions = {
  styles: [{
      height: 53,
      url: "pic_link",
      width: 53
    },
    {
      height: 40,
      url: "pic_link",
      width: 46
    }
  ]
};
```

and call the constructor

```
var clust= new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mOptions);
```